# Is there any way to expose Prometheus api in core java without using spring boot

Tags: java, streaming, micrometer

I have a java application which uses streaming. I have to implement micrometer in that application.
The application is not based on spring boot but instead it is core java.
I have this link for reference but it is all I could find which is not that elaborate.
https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/learningpaths/application-observability/exposing-metrics-java-prometheus/
Please refer "Vanilla Java reference"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the official docs?
https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus

Comment: I have an existing application and I need a way to wire the function to the api. Yes I have read the documentation.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you need is on that page.